# IPv6 network is unreachable. until reboot

Tags: networking, server, ipv6

I've setup IPv6 on my Ubuntu 14.04 server.
Everything is working.. until all of a sudden (haven't found the trigger)
a `ping6 2001:4860:4860::8888` (google nameserver 8.8.8.8) returns network unreachable.

When i reboot the server it all starts working again. and the ping resolves.

My /etc/network/interfaces:

```
# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
iface lo inet6 loopback

# The primary network interface
auto eth0

iface eth0 inet static
address 95.xxx.44.xxx
netmask 255.255.255.0
network 95.xxx.44.0
broadcast 95.xxx.44.255
gateway 95.xxx.44.254
dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
dns-search localdomain

iface eth0 inet6 static
pre-up modprobe ipv6
address 2001:xxxx:4300:xxxx:0008::c01a
netmask 64
gateway 2001:xxxx:4300:xxxx::1
dns-nameservers 2001:4860:4860::8888 2001:4860:4860::8844
dns-search localdomain
```

I have found that my `/run/network/ifstate` is sometimes missing the `eth0=eth0`
but with or without it the problems occur.

EDIT:
both where when everything was NOT working.
output of `ip -6 addr`:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 
inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qlen 1000
inet6 2001:xxxx:4300:xxxx:8::69/64 scope global 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 2001:xxxx:4300:xxxx:8::68/64 scope global 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 2001:xxxx:4300:xxxx:8::67/64 scope global 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 2001:xxxx:4300:xxxx:8::66/64 scope global 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 2001:xxxx:4300:xxxx:8::65/64 scope global 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 2001:xxxx:4300:xxxx:8::64/64 scope global 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 2001:xxxx:4300:xxxx:8::63/64 scope global 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 2001:xxxx:4300:xxxx:8::62/64 scope global 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 2001:xxxx:4300:xxxx:8::61/64 scope global 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 2001:xxxx:4300:xxxx:8::60/64 scope global 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 2001:xxxx:4300:xxxx:8::59/64 scope global 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 2001:xxxx:4300:xxxx:8::58/64 scope global 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 2001:xxxx:4300:xxxx:8::57/64 scope global 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 2001:xxxx:4300:xxxx:8::56/64 scope global 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 2001:xxxx:4300:xxxx:8::55/64 scope global 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 2001:xxxx:4300:xxxx:8::54/64 scope global 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 2001:xxxx:4300:xxxx:8::53/64 scope global 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 2001:xxxx:4300:xxxx:8::52/64 scope global 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 2001:xxxx:4300:xxxx:8::51/64 scope global 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 2001:xxxx:4300:xxxx:8::50/64 scope global 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 2001:xxxx:4300:xxxx:8::49/64 scope global 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 2001:xxxx:4300:xxxx:8::48/64 scope global 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 2001:xxxx:4300:xxxx:8::47/64 scope global 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 2001:xxxx:4300:xxxx:8::46/64 scope global 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 2001:xxxx:4300:xxxx:8::45/64 scope global 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 2001:xxxx:4300:xxxx:8::44/64 scope global 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 2001:xxxx:4300:xxxx:8::43/64 scope global 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 2001:xxxx:4300:xxxx:8::42/64 scope global 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 2001:xxxx:4300:xxxx:8::41/64 scope global 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 2001:xxxx:4300:xxxx:8::40/64 scope global 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 2001:xxxx:4300:xxxx:8::39/64 scope global 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 2001:xxxx:4300:xxxx:8::38/64 scope global 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 2001:xxxx:4300:xxxx:8::37/64 scope global 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 2001:xxxx:4300:xxxx:8::36/64 scope global 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 2001:xxxx:4300:xxxx:8::35/64 scope global 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 2001:xxxx:4300:xxxx:8::34/64 scope global 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 2001:xxxx:4300:xxxx:8::33/64 scope global 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 2001:xxxx:4300:xxxx:8::32/64 scope global 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 2001:xxxx:4300:xxxx:8::31/64 scope global 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 2001:xxxx:4300:xxxx:8::30/64 scope global 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 2001:xxxx:4300:xxxx:8::29/64 scope global 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 2001:xxxx:4300:xxxx:8::28/64 scope global 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 2001:xxxx:4300:xxxx:8::27/64 scope global 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 2001:xxxx:4300:xxxx:8::26/64 scope global 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 2001:xxxx:4300:xxxx:8::25/64 scope global 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 2001:xxxx:4300:xxxx:8::24/64 scope global 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 2001:xxxx:4300:xxxx:8::23/64 scope global 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 2001:xxxx:4300:xxxx:8::22/64 scope global 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 2001:xxxx:4300:xxxx:8::21/64 scope global 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 2001:xxxx:4300:xxxx:8::20/64 scope global 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 2001:xxxx:4300:xxxx:8::19/64 scope global 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 2001:xxxx:4300:xxxx:8::18/64 scope global 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 2001:xxxx:4300:xxxx:8::17/64 scope global 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 2001:xxxx:4300:xxxx:8::16/64 scope global 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 2001:xxxx:4300:xxxx:8::15/64 scope global 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 2001:xxxx:4300:xxxx:8::14/64 scope global 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 2001:xxxx:4300:xxxx:8::13/64 scope global 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 2001:xxxx:4300:xxxx:8::12/64 scope global 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 2001:xxxx:4300:xxxx:8::11/64 scope global 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 2001:xxxx:4300:xxxx:8::10/64 scope global 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 2001:xxxx:4300:xxxx:8::9/64 scope global 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 2001:xxxx:4300:xxxx:8::8/64 scope global 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 2001:xxxx:4300:xxxx:8::7/64 scope global 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 2001:xxxx:4300:xxxx:8::6/64 scope global 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 2001:xxxx:4300:xxxx:8::5/64 scope global 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 2001:xxxx:4300:xxxx:8::4/64 scope global 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 2001:xxxx:4300:xxxx:8::3/64 scope global 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 2001:xxxx:4300:xxxx:8::2/64 scope global 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 2001:xxxx:4300:xxxx:8::1/64 scope global 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 2001:xxxx:4300:xxxx:8::/64 scope global 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 2001:xxxx:4300:xxxx:8::c01a/64 scope global 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 fe80::250:xxxx:xxxx:9b1/64 scope link 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

and output of `ip -6 route`:

```
 2001:xxxx:4300:xxxx::/64 dev eth0  proto kernel  metric 256 
 fe80::/64 dev eth0  proto kernel  metric 256
```

EDIT2:
output of `ip -6 route` when networking was working:

```
2001:xxxx:4300:xxxx::/64 dev eth0  proto kernel  metric 256 
fe80::/64 dev eth0  proto kernel  metric 256 
default via fe80::2d0:ff:fefc:3000 dev eth0  proto ra  metric 1024  expires 1772sec
default via fe80::2d0:ff:fefb:9000 dev eth0  proto ra  metric 1024  expires 1772sec
```

Comment: Can you add the output of the commands `ip -6 addr` and `ip -6 route`?

Comment: This is strange. Where do all those IPv6 addresses (`...:8::` to `...:8::69`) come from? Also your routing table doesn't have a default route anymore. You did configure a gateway, but it has disappeared. Something else is interfering with your IPv6 settings...

Comment: You say the output was from when things are working fine, but without a default route that can't be. You don't have a route to reach i.e. `2001:4860:4860::8888`.

Comment: You are right.. it is not working.. again.. Thats what i mean, everything is fine one moment, and the next it doesn't work anymore..

Comment: all those IPv6 addresses `(...:8:: to ...:8::69)` come from DirectAdmin .. somewhere..  BTW. i say DirectAdmin, but i'm experiencing this behavior on a different server as well without DirectAdmin.

Comment: You should see `default via 2001:xxxx:4300:xxxx::1 dev eth0  metric 1024` in your `ip -6 route` output. Something is removing it. You might want to see if there is any correlation between certain cronjobs running and this behaviour. Maybe run `ping6 -a 2001:4860:4860::8888` while running `tail -f /var/log/syslog` in a different window and see what showed up in the logs the moment the beeps stop.

Comment: hello Sander, checked the syslog while pinging.. at the moment the beeps stopped it was /usr/local/directadmin/dataskq which was executed (it is executed every minute but it happens only after an half an hour.)

Comment: `dataskq` is the DirectAdmin Task Queue runner. I never used DirectAdmin so I don't know which kind of tasks are executed by it. I think someone with more DA experience has to answer this...

Answer (score 3):

It appears you have two devices advertising the default route instead of 1. (These could be two interfaces on your router.)  These routes normally are sent by a `radvd` server.  Your router should be periodically advertizing it routes.

```
default via fe80::2d0:ff:fefc:3000 dev eth0  proto ra  metric 1024  expires 1772sec
default via fe80::2d0:ff:fefb:9000 dev eth0  proto ra  metric 1024  expires 1772sec
```

Try running `tcpdump` to catch the router advertisements.  Identify the device which is advertising an incorrect route and stop it from advertising itself as a router.   If you aren't seeing advertisements, try to get your router configured to send them.

You may be able to temporarily restore connectivity with the command:

```
ip -6 route add default via 2001:xxxx:4300:xxxx::1 dev eth0 metric 1024
```

If you are firewalling ICMP6 traffic, you may be blocking traffic required for IPv6 to work.  There is a long list of ICMP types that are required: at least 1-4, 130-137, 141-143, 148-148, and 151-153.  See RFC4890 for more information.

Check the contents of `/etc/sysctl.conf` and `/etc/sysctl` to see if you have disabled `ipv6.autoconf` on your interface.

Comment: you might be on to something here. i just noticed (since ipv6 is up and running for an hour) that `ip -6 route` now only displays one additional route instead of the two mentioned above.

Comment: ps. when trying the `add route` it says network unreachable.
ps2. the one route displayed is a route to the first ipv6 address. not the ff:fefb:3000 / 9000 address.

Comment: @TD_Nijboer If you have the original two as well as a new one, try removing the new one.  I have found I often need to add or alter options when manually configuring IPv6.  There is a option listed on the `ip` man page to force add a route that does not seem to be reachable. Default routing is normally done via an `fe80::` address.

Comment: the only `fe80` route i have is `fe80::/64 dev eth0 proto kernel  metric 256` and now `default via 2001:xxxx:4300:xxxx::1 dev eth0  metric 1024` this is working fine.. for now.